# Render rmarkdown from RStudio server to external drive

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny-server, rstudio-server

When working locally, I use the following to render rmarkdown documents:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = rmd.temp , output_dir = out.dir, output_file = out.name)
```

This gets my template doc `rmd.temp`, then renders the document to `out.dir` and names the file `out.name`.

I am trying to replicate on a RStudio server. When `out.dir` is a local directory the code works fine. However, when`out.dir` is a mapped directory to an external drive, I get the following error:

```
Error in replayPlot(x) : 
  could not open file'/...path..../figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png'
```

The link to the mapped drive works because I can use:

```
dir.create(out.dir)
```

and see the new folder appear. Any ideas why the rendering gets stuck?

**Update**

This is perhaps just a permission problem because I can't write a csv file either:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10)

setwd(out.dir)

write.csv(df, file = "df.csv")

Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

RStudio server is running on Ubuntu. I will open a new question on how to give RStudio folder permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem, it can be fixed by adding this to the start of your script:

```
Sys.umask(mode="0000")
```

It was a permission problem. From the shell / command line, global permission was "0000" but from the RStudio console it was "0002", which produces -rw-r-- permissions for new files. The global permission can probably be changed for RStudio but this works.